# How to find cardinality of set of linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question: given

$S= \{T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3:$ T is linear operator with, $T(1,0,1) = (1,2,3), T(1,2,3) = (1,0,1)\}$

Then $|S| = ?$

I am confused how to start! I think here we can't derive a formula for given linear transformation. Further clearly $T$ is not zero transformation or identity transformations. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hence $u_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$,$u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $u_3= u_1 \times u_2$.

Then $u_1, u_2, u_3$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $x=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3$

$$T_C(x)=a_2u_1+a_1u_2+Ca_3u_3$$

We can see that for each $C$, $T_C \in S$.

Can you conclude about the size of $S$?

Comment: Why you had taken cross product of $u_1$ and $u_2$? (Is just to form basis of $R^3$ ? ) and how you derive,$T_c(x)$ ?

Comment: Yup, to form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. We can actually map the $u_3$ component to anything, but I just construct something explicit. I map $u_1$ to $u_2$, $u_2$ to $u_1$ and $u_3$ to $Cu_3$.

Comment: You had taken $u_3 = u_1 × u_2$ and we know by cross product in 3-space, $u_1 × u_2 = (-2, -2, 2)$. Now you had taken, $X$ in $R^3$. That is $X= (x, y, z)$ so $X = a_1 u_1 + a_2 u_2 + a_3 u_3$. So that $T(X) = a_1T(u_1) + a_2 T(u_2) + a_3 T(u_3) = a_1 u2 + a_2 u_1 + a_3 T(u_3)$ then how to derive $T(u_3) = T(-2,-2,2) =?$

Comment: You get to choose $T(u_3)$ to be anything. I just choose $T(u_3) = Cu_3$, it is just a choice.  You can also say choose $T(u_3)=Cu1$ if you like.

Comment: So how can be you sure for each $C$ , $T_C$ is in $S$. If so how we conclude from this, the cardinality of $S$?

Comment: Just verify that $T_C$ is linear and they satisfy the condition. If for every $C \in \mathbb{R}$, $T_C \in S$, the cardinality of $S$ must be at least as big as $|\mathbb{R}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at what the linear transform does. It is mapping the linearly independent vectors (1,0,1) and (1,2,3) into each other, taking care of two dimensions out of three. What about the third element of the basis? Can it be mapped to any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Try to write down why. How many such linear transforms can you have?